# dart HttpRequest.getString not working with

Tags: javascript, web, dart

I'm using the HttpRequest.getString method to load some content dynamically, which works well until I generate some js from the dart code.
Running the generated javascript causes these error "access denied" at this point:

```
// An uncaught error in the root context terminates all isolates.
    if (identical(this, _globalState.rootContext)) {
      rethrow;
    }
```

this is the dart code:

```
void loadPage(String src)
{
  HttpRequest.getString(src).then((response)
  {
    querySelector("#content").innerHtml=response;
  });
}
```

Where is the problem, and why is the dart code working but not the javascript code?

Comment: You should show the JS generated.

Comment: the javascript debugger says "_globalState" is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could try `setInnerHtml()` with a `NodeValidator` like shown in [How to change Element innerHtml to Dart SDK 0.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649338). See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/kQD2-_hY_DQ

Comment: This is also working in dartium but not with the generated js